# Amazon Corretto Java 8 for Sun Solaris?

Tags: java, java-8, adoptopenjdk, corretto

Does Amazon Corretto Java 8 is supported in Solaris platform?
Can anyone know where to download and the installation instruction?

Comment: The answer is no and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/downloads-list.html) is the downloads list.

Comment: Which Open JDK provides Solaris support?

Answer (score 0):

No. It supports Amazon Linux, and Debian- and RPM-based distributions. [Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/linux-info.html)

There is [an Oracle JRE 8 for Solaris](https://java.com/en/download/help/solaris_install.xml). This [blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/solaris/update-on-oracle-java-on-oracle-solaris) may also be useful (though mostly advocates building it from source!)